# Why new table not created in sql database after migration in mvc codefirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

Run the command `Enable-Migrations`

`Add-Migration X` with X being whatever name you want to give this migration

But After this migration if i create any new Table why its not Generated in db

Comment: have you run "Update-Database" on your package manager console?

Comment: everytime you change your classes, you should again run "Add-Migration" then "Update-Database"

Comment: u Mean previous migration folder i have to delete i again i create new

Comment: no, just run "Add-Migration" again everytime you change the database, for example, from the beginning: step 1: "Enable-Migration" step 2: create a new table step 3: "Add-Migration migration1" step 4: "Update-Database" step 5: modify table step 6: "Add-Migration migration2" step 7: "Update-Database" ...and so on and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after creating your class  need to set the table in the dbcontext  like:

```html
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
    public DbSet<User> User {get;set;}
    }


public class User
{
    [key]
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}
```

create the migration and update the database